# Any reason why my method to check if there is even parenthesis etc is not working?

Tags: java, arrays, input, methods, boolean

I made a program that deals with asking the user to input a equation such as { x + (y - 2) * 1} + [ a + b] and checking if every parenthesis and bracket etc closes. If my method spots that it closes it will print: Expression: { x + (y - 2) * 1} + [ a + b] -> is balanced. My problem is my method seems to default to unbalanced everytime so I suspect its a problem within the isBalanced method.Could anyone just let me know if my syntax is wrong? It seems to flow well when i read it.
Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class BalancedParanthesis {
        static String expressions[];
        static class    MyArrayStack{
            int top = -1;
            char brackets[] = new char[100];
            void push(char x) {
                if(top ==99) {
                    System.out.print("Stack full");
                }
                else {
                    brackets[++top] = x;
                }
                }
            char pop() {
                if(top ==-1) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR:Stack undeflow error");
                    return '\0';
                }
                else {
                    char element = brackets[top];
                    top--;
                    return element; 
                }
            }

            boolean isEmpty() {
                return(top==-1)?true:false;
            }
        }
        static boolean isMatchingPair(char bracketOne,char bracketTwo) {
            if(bracketOne=='('&& bracketTwo ==')') {
                return true;
            }
            else if(bracketOne == '{'&& bracketTwo == '}') {
                return true;
            }
            else if(bracketOne == '['&& bracketTwo ==']') {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }

        }
        static boolean isBalanced(String expression) {
            MyArrayStack st =new MyArrayStack();
            for(int index = 0; index<expression.length();index++) {
                if(expression.charAt(index)=='{'|| expression.charAt(index)=='(' || expression.charAt(index)=='{') {
                    st.push(expression.charAt(index));
                }
                if(expression.charAt(index)=='}'|| expression.charAt(index)==')'||expression.charAt(index)=='}'){
                        if(st.isEmpty()) {
                            return false;
                        }
                }
                else if(!isMatchingPair(st.pop(),expression.charAt(index))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            if(st.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Input: ");
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            String x = input.next();
            if(isBalanced(x)) {
                System.out.println("\n Expression: " + x + " is balanced");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("\n Expression: " + x + " is not balanced");
            }
        }

        }
```

Comment: did you try to use a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See logic flaws in comments:

```
// why are we checking for `{` twice here?
if(expression.charAt(index)=='{'|| expression.charAt(index)=='(' || expression.charAt(index)=='{') {
    st.push(expression.charAt(index));
} // missing 'else' here, maybe??
// why are we checking for `}` twice here?
if(expression.charAt(index)=='}'|| expression.charAt(index)==')'||expression.charAt(index)=='}'){
    if(st.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    // shouldn't we be calling pop() and isMatchingPair() here?
}
// here we know that charAt(index) is not a ')' or '}',
// so why are we calling pop() and isMatchingPair()?
else if(!isMatchingPair(st.pop(),expression.charAt(index))) {
    return false;
}
```

```
// isEmpty() returns a boolean, so why not return it directly?
if(st.isEmpty()) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

For better performance *and* code clarity, only call `expression.charAt(index)` once.

```
char ch = expression.charAt(index);
if (ch == '(' || ch == '{' || ch == '[') {
    st.push(ch);
} else if (ch == ')' || ch == '}' || ch == ']'){
    if (st.isEmpty()) {
        return false;
    }
    if (! isMatchingPair(st.pop(), ch)) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
return st.isEmpty();
```

Comment: Thank you man your code ended up fixing the problem, may you explain the else if statement part in your code ? I understand the false statements but I am confused on what is happening if both chars match like [ and ]

Comment: @Gtown Since `ch` cannot be both `[` and `]` the `else` has no visible effect, it just tells the compiler that if the first check for the open bracket is true, there is no need to check for close bracket. It's a microscopic performance improvement, but really it's a logic improvement to say that we're done with the `if-elseif-else` construct. That would matter if we had an `else` at the end, like your original code has. For this code it doesn't really matter, but it's good to get into the habit of writing good logic like this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite weird code tbh...
Just read it like a string. Convert to char array. Three integers for (,{,[. If char is ),},] then do -1 on the according int. If all three ints are 0 the term is correct!

```
public static boolean validate(String s) {
    int bracket = 0;
    int squareBracket = 0;
    int brace = 0;
    for(char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        switch (c) {
            case '(': bracket++; break;
            case ')': bracket--; break;
            case '[': squareBracket++; break;
            case ']': squareBracket--; break;
            case '{': brace++; break;
            case '}': brace--; break;
            default: break;
        }
    }
    return(bracket == 0 && squareBracket == 0 && brace == 0);
}
```

Comment: This won't work. `{ a + ( b + c } )` would be valid

Comment: No, you create THREE integers: one for (), one for [] and one for {}. For each opening bracket you do +1 to the according int, for closing bracket -1. If all three ints are 0 at the end, the string is valid.

Comment: yea, so with my example, it will return 0, but the bracket is closed before the parenthesis, so it's invalid

Comment: your code only checks the number of opening/closing characters, not their consistency (i.e: check if the next closing character is a parenthesis  if the previous opening char was a parenthesis). Test your code with `"({)}"`

Comment: That is correct. Then you could also write all brackets to a chararray and then read chars from beginning and end. If chararray.length % 2 != 0, then you can directly return false.